# “Show Obj-C only” setting is missing in Instruments 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

Since my latest update to the Instruments 6.1 I can't find "Show Obj-C only" checkbox anymore. Does somebody know if it has been removed completely or where one can find it?

Please, see attached images.

old Instruments checkBoxes:
[image]

new Instruments checkBoxes:
[image]

Comment: I'm also looking for the missing *show obj-c*. It's pretty annoying without this option.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the [Instruments User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/InstrumentsUserGuide.pdf) by Apple you stumble upon many screenshots of the UI. All of them are missing the "show obj-c only" section. They definitely removed the feature from instruments.

One of the reasons may be that according to the [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW1) instruments supports swift (*Instruments supports Swift, displaying Swift symbols in stack traces*) and therefore they would have to either change the title of the feature or add a similar feature for swift. They apparently choose to remove it entirely since almost all of its functionality can be achieved by using the "Hide System Libraries" option and "Data Mining" section.

[@Aaron Brager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445366/aaron-brager) asked about the topic [in the apple developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1132885#1132885) as well and received pretty much the same answer.

=> **Apple felt like its functionality was redundant and it could/should be removed! Therefore they acted accordingly.**

P.S.: as the answerer in the dev forum asks: if you have a use case that got more difficult, feel free to [file a bug report](http://bugreporter.apple.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed this and while it's not exactly the same, I use the following toggle in the new interface builder to focus on my personal code:

Toggle Off:

[image: code toggle off]

Toggle On:

[image: code toggle on]

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like the equivalent of the "Hide System Libraries" checkbox. This is a bit helpful, but I still want to see Obj-C system libraries.

Comment: totally agree with the previous comment, this does not solve the problem at all